# Windows 8 very slow boot time and warning with event ID 153

Tags: windows-8, boot, event-log

I have an Acer aspire 6920g notebook. I use this old laptop just for some basic tasks and testing. Currently it is dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu. When I turn it on the first time I log into Windows I can't access internet but anything else works fine (the boot time is OK too) Then I have to restart for the internet access but when I log into windows for the second time the boot time is awfully long and HDD is at 100%.
I looked at Event logs and see that with every boot I have some errors:

```
Event ID    Source

23          Eventlog
46          volmgr
7000        Service Control Manager
7009        Service Control Manager
```

Also with every boot I get numerous (around 50) warnings of this type:

```
Event ID    Source

153         disk
```

I googled it and found some info but the odd thing is that my logical block address is reported as some Chinese characters:

```
The IO operation at logical block address 㜀㤀攀挀㠀 for Disk 　 was retried.
```

Update: I did the extended test of WindDig and it reported the test failed with the error code of "08-" but I can't find the error code in [WD support page](http://support.wdc.com/techinfo/general/errorcodes.asp)

Comment: Your laptop was released in 2008 and originally came with Windows Vista. The official [Acer support page](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers) only provides Windows Vista and Windows 7 drivers. Windows 8.x is not officially supported. What's the hard disk model? Did you try scanning the disk for errors using the official diagnostic tools already?

Comment: @and31415 You are right but it was working fine since the launch of Windows 8 and this problem started last week. Yes I used many diagnostic tools, all results are fine but CrystalDiskInfo shows a yellow caution as my disk health status. It is a WDC WD2500BEVS-22UST0. The fact that the laptop is working fine with Ubuntu makes me wonder if it is a Windows related problem not HDD.

Comment: I suspect the issue is hardware related. The most accurate results can be obtained by using [http://support.wd.com/product/download.asp?groupid=810&sid=3&lang=en](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=612&sid=3). Make sure to choose the Extended Test if you haven't already.